# Como exportar mas de una fila del thead de un datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

He trabajado mucho tiempo sin problemas con el plugin de Datable pero no podido entontrar una solucion o alternativa a este inconveniente. En mi tabla tengo dos filas en la cabcera o en el thead, pero al exportar a excel la tabla solamente me trae la segunda fila, alguien que tenga experiencia en esto podria ayudarme. YA intentado varias cosas que plantea la comunidad de DataTable pero no me han funcionado
.

Esta es la estructura de la tabla

```
<table class="table-striped table-condensed  table-hover" id="dyntable2" style="width:100%">
                <colgroup>
                    <col class="con0" style="text-align: center; width: 7%"     />                
                    <col class="con0" style="text-align: center; width: 5%"     />
                    <col class="con0" style="text-align: center; width: 7%"     />
                    <col class="con0" style="text-align: center; width: 5%"     />
                    <col class="con0" style="text-align: center; width: 6%"     />
                    <col class="con0" style="text-align: center; width: 6%"     />
                    <col class="con0" style="text-align: center; width: 5%"     />
                    <col class="con0" style="text-align: center; width: 5%"     />
                    <col class="con0" style="text-align: center; width: 5%"     />
                    <col class="con0" style="text-align: center; width: 5%"     />
                    <col class="con0" style="text-align: center; width: 6%"     />
                    <col class="con0" style="text-align: center; width: 6%"     />
                    <col class="con0" style="text-align: center; width: 6%"     />
                    <col class="con0" style="text-align: center; width: 6%"     />
                    <col class="con0" style="text-align: center; width: 6%"     />
                    <col class="con0" style="text-align: center; width: 6%"     />
                    <col class="con0" style="text-align: center; width: 6%"     />
                    <col class="con0" style="text-align: center; width: 6%"     />
                    <col class="con0" style="text-align: center; width: 6%"     />
                    <col class="con0" style="text-align: center; width: 3%"     />
                </colgroup>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="5"></th>
                        <th class="head0 center" id="totalsaldoi"></th>
                        <th class="head0 center" id="totalPag2"></th>
                        <th class="head0 center" id="totalGenerado"></th>
                        <th class="head0 center" id="totalDiferencia"></th>
                        <th class="head0 center" id="totalIng"></th>
                        <th class="head0 center" id="totalPag"></th>
                        <th class="head0 center" id="totalFac"></th>
                        <th class="head0 center" id="totalSinFac"></th>
                        <th class="head0 center" id="totalOc"></th>
                        <th class="head0 center" id="totalSinOc"></th>
                        <th class="head0 center" id="totalF"></th>
                        <th class="head0 center" id="totalSinFecha"></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="td-table-custom head0 center nosort">U. Negocio</th>                    
                        <th class="td-table-custom head0 center">Cliente</th>
                        <th class="td-table-custom head0 center">Proyecto</th>
                        <th class="td-table-custom head0 center">P.U.</th>
                        <th class="td-table-custom head0 center">Moneda</th>
                        <th class="td-table-custom head0 center">Saldo Inicial</th>                                    
                        <th class="td-table-custom head0 center">Pagado F.</th>
                        <th class="td-table-custom head0 center">Balance F.</th>
                        <th class="td-table-custom head0 center">Diferencia</th> 
                        <th class="td-table-custom head0 center">Monto Total</th>
                        <th class="td-table-custom head0 center">Pagado</th>
                        <th class="td-table-custom head0 center">Balance Facturado</th> 
                        <th class="td-table-custom head0 center">Balance Sin Facturar</th>
                        <th class="td-table-custom head0 center">Con OCs</th>
                        <th class="td-table-custom head0 center">Sin OCs</th>
                        <th class="td-table-custom head0 center">C. F. P.</th>
                        <th class="td-table-custom head0 center">S. F. P.</th>
                        <th class="td-table-custom head0 center">Coments</th>
                        <th class="td-table-custom head0 center">Fecha</th>
                        <th class="td-table-custom head0 center">Calif</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                   Registros que lleno con un bucle con PHP
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Este es el script para exportarlo

```
    var table =jQuery('#dyntable2').DataTable({
        dom: 'Blfrtip',
        "scrollX": true,
        buttons: [
            { extend: 'excel', className: 'btn btn-success btn-rounded  buttonExcel hide', title: 'Reporte de Adeudos', text: 'Excel', footer: true, },
        ],
    });
```

[image: Esta es la como se exporta con una fila en la cabecera en lugar de dos]
Esta es como me exporta la tabla solamente con una fila en lugar de dos en la cabecera

[image: Aqui es como se ve para el cliente con las dos filas en la cabecera]
Y esta es como se muestra al usuario con dos filas en la cabecera

Comment: Creo que esto puede ayudarte a responder tu pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660683/tabletools-only-exporting-single-header-row/14813085#14813085